# Moving elements in DOM on resize using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom, elementor

First, please note that I'm using Elementor Pro for this project, then I can't use css easily because the html structure is complex. That's why I'm trying to do this with Javascript.

[image]

I'd like to move my image above my h1 title for tablets and mobile, and that it stays above the description on larger screens.

Here is my code (pure javascript, no jquery)

```
let title = document.getElementById("product-title");
let image = document.getElementById("product-image");
let resizeProductPage = function () {
        if(typeof(title) != 'undefined' && title != null){
            let width = window.innerWidth;
            if (width<1025)
                title.parentNode.insertBefore(image, title);
            else
                image.parentNode.insertBefore(title, image);
        }
  };
resizeProductPage();
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeProductPage);
```

but it doesn't work, and I find the code rather complex. would you have an idea?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Do those elements have those IDs? Is the width small enough to change things? Do you get any errors? Does the function run at all?

Comment: Side note: Since `title` refers to an element (or `null`), your `if` can be just `if (title)`. Elements are truthy, `null` is falsy.

Comment: Assuming the elements exist and the function is called, that should work: https://codesandbox.io/s/re-so-question-68758748-ckr5b

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, but here is what you should do.

1. Under edit with elementor, at the component editor you
   should be able to specify the ID for the title element to: `product-title` & the image element to: `product-image`
2. Your conditional checking if the title element exists should be adapted to just `if (title)` as it will return false if that element does not exist.

Other than that your code should be working fine, I made a working solution as a snippet.

```js
let title = document.getElementById("product-title");
let image = document.getElementById("product-image");
let resizeProductPage = function() {
  if (title) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1025)
      title.parentNode.insertBefore(image, title);
    else
      image.parentNode.insertBefore(title, image);
  }
};
resizeProductPage();
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeProductPage);
```

```css
#product-image {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

#product-image p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="product-title">Product Title</h1>
<div id="product-image">
  <p>Image Here</p>
</div>
```